# Converting a string of chars into its decimal value then back to its character valus

Tags: c

```
unsigned long long int power(int base, unsigned int exponent)
{
    if (exponent == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

I am working on a program where I need to take in a string of 8 characters (e.g. "I want t") then convert this into a long long int in the pack function. I have the pack function working fine.

```
unsigned long long int pack(char unpack[])
{
    /*converting string to long long int here
      didn't post code because its large*/
}
```

After I enter "I want t" I get "Value in Decimal = 5269342824372117620" and then I send the decimal to the unpack function. So I need to convert 5269342824372117620 back into "I want t". I tried bit manipulation which was unsuccessful any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void unpack(long long int pack)
{
    long long int bin;
    char convert[100];

    for(int i = 63, j = 0, k = 0; i >= 0; i--,j++)
    {
        if((pack & (1 << i)) != 0)
            bin += power(2,j);

        if(j % 8 == 0)
        {
            convert[k] = (char)bin;
            bin = 0;
            k++;
            j = -1;
        }
    } 
   printf("String: %s\n", convert);
}
```

Comment: The answer depends on how you wrote your `pack`.

Comment: If you used bit operations to pack, just need to use the inverse of those operations to unpack.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for your problem is to consider the characters in the string to be *digits* in a large base that encompasses all possible values. For example *base64* encoding can convert strings of 8 characters to 48-bit numbers, but you can only use a subset of at most 64 different characters in the source string.

To convert any 8 byte string into a number, you must use a base of at least 256.

Given your extra input, *After I enter "I want t" I get "Value in Decimal = 5269342824372117620"*, and since `5269342824372117620 == 0x492077616e742074`, you do indeed use base 256, big-endian order and ASCII encoding for the characters.

Here is a simple portable `pack` function for this method:

```
unsigned long long pack(const char *s) {
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        x = x * 256 + (unsigned char)s[i];
    }
    return x;
}
```

The `unpack` function is easy to derive: compute the remainders of divisions in the reverse order:

```
char *unpack(char *dest, unsigned long long x) {
    /* dest is assumed to have a length of at least 9 */
    int i;
    for (i = 8; i-- > 0; ) {
        s[i] = x % 256;
        x = x / 256;
    }
    s[8] = '\0';  /* set the null terminator */
    return s;
}
```

For a potentially faster but less portable solution, you could use this, but you would get a different conversion on little-endian systems such as current Macs and PCs:

```
#include <string.h>

unsigned long long pack(const char *s) {
    unsigned long long x;
    memcpy(&x, s, 8);
    return x;
}

char *unpack(char *s, unsigned long long x) {
    memcpy(s, &x, 8);
    s[8] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```